# Is it possible to have multiple route entries for Vuejs in a Laravel App?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I'm building a Laravel app and I'm using Vuejs on the frontend, is it possible to have two instances of Vue running in laravel. Currently doing this causes crashes when accessing routes. I'm guessing this error comes from Laravel routing and not vue.

`web.php`

```
    Route::get('/{user?}', function () {
          return view('enduser.home');
      })->where('user', '.*')->name('enduser.app');

      Route::get('/{admin?}', function () {
          return view('admin.dashboard');
      })->where('admin', '.*')->name('admin.app');
```

`app1.js`

```
     window.Vue = require('vue');
    import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
    Vue.use(VueRouter);

    import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
    import axios from 'axios';
    Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);

    const routes = [
      {
          name: 'adminIndex',
          path: '/dashboard/home',
          component: IndexComponent
      },
    ]
    const router = new VueRouter({ mode: 'history', routes: routes});
    const appboard = new Vue(Vue.util.extend({ router }, MainApp)).$mount('#appadmin');
```

`app2.js`

```
     window.Vue = require('vue');
    import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
    Vue.use(VueRouter);

    import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
    import axios from 'axios';
    Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);

    const routes = [
      {
          name: 'userIndex',
          path: '/user/home',
          component: IndexComponent
      },
    ]
    const router = new VueRouter({ mode: 'history', routes: routes});
    const appboard = new Vue(Vue.util.extend({ router }, MainApp)).$mount('#appuser');
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding a Route group with a prefix in Laravel.